# Ruby server won't start with neography

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, sinatra, neography

I have ruby file which im running in my mac with OSX 10.9 that is a combination of sinatra and geography which i have both installed. when i use `require 'sinatra'` on the file everything is fine, but when i insert `require 'neography'` it gives me this error when trying to run the file.

```
/Users/AJ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1-head/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1488:in `start_server': undefined method `run' for HTTP:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/AJ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1-head/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1426:in `run!'
        from /Users/AJ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1-head/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

What could be a possible reason for this error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Neography [depends on httpclient](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/blob/v1.3.7/lib/neography.rb#L2), which in turn [defines a module named `HTTP`](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/blob/v2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/http.rb#L16).

When Sinatra tries to determine which server to use one of the options it tries is the [net-http-server](http://rubygems.org/gems/net-http-server), whose Rack handler class is also named `HTTP`. This causes a name collision where Sinatra thinks the `HTTP` module in httpclient is the net-http-server and tries to run it as such, causing the error you see.

If you have another server installed, e.g. [Thin](http://rubygems.org/gems/thin), it will likely be detected before `HTTP` so you won’t see this error, but you are probably better [explicitly setting the server to use](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#server---handler-used-for-built-in-web-server). You can add something like

```ruby
set :server, thin
```

to your application file to specify Thin as your server (you’ll need to install the `thin` gem first – you could also use Webrick). You could also specify this on the command line if you wanted: `ruby my_app.rb -s thin`, but I think you’d be better of adding it to your code to avoid problems in the future.